# htaccess rewriterule redirect everypage to a single page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect every url  to a single php file that will act as a dispatcher that will pull content from a DB based on the url. I am unsure what is wrong with this. Any pointers please.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/admin/) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/robots\.txt$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpeg$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.pdf$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.GIF$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.xml$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.js$) 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.ico$) 

RewriteRule . pageDispatcher.php   [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (?!^admin/)^.*$ pageDispatcher.php [L]
```